# Difference between '?' and 'help()'

Tags: python

What is the difference between '?' and 'help()' in Python Jupyter Notebooks. E.g.

```
import scipy
help(scipy)
?scipy
```

Comment: Are you using Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes I am using Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: And do you see any difference? If not, what exactly is your question about?

Comment: I see a difference. In the specific case I am currently looking at, help() returns something while ? does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentations are always a good place to start. :)

So, `?` which is a [**magic**](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html), is equivalent to `%pinfo` as specified in the [IPython docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pinfo).

Whereas `help()` is a **built-in** Python function that returns the documentation associated with a Python Object.

#p.s. Jupyter uses an IPython (or Interactive Python) kernel, which supports the `magics`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the ? symbol is used to display the documentation string of **an object**, while the help() function is used to display the documentation for **a module, function, or object**.

Here is an example of how to use these two methods in Python:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]

>>> x?
Type:        list
String form: [1, 2, 3]
Length:      3
Docstring:  
Built-in mutable sequence.

>>> help(list)
Help on class list in module builtins:

class list(object)
    list() -> new empty list
    list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
    
    Methods defined here:
    
    __add__(self, value, /)
        Return self+value.
    
    __contains__(self, key, /)
        Return key in self.
    
    __delitem__(self, key, /)
        Delete self[key].
```

Comment: You say "In Python, the ? symbol is used [...]". That's not correct. The `?` is not valid in Python. It might be used from some REPLs like IPython or Jupyter.